# Is it possible to pass an array to a prepared statement on Amazon Redshift?

Tags: prepared-statement, amazon-redshift, user-defined-functions

I need to pass an array to a prepared statement defined on AWS Redshift to filter my query. Since this is not supported in Redshift, I was trying to find a work around using a Python UDF. Something like:

```
-- a function to split a comma separated list of values (string is already validated)

CREATE FUNCTION split_str_to_ints (string char) RETURNS int[] IMMUTABLE as $$
    def split_stoi(string):
      ints = [int(item) for item in string.split(',')]
      return ints
$$ LANGUAGE plpythonu;
```

```
-- a prepared statement to return orders filtered by company id

PREPARE get_orders (char) as 
SELECT order.id
       order.company_id,
       COUNT(order.id) AS order_count
FROM order
  INNER JOIN company ON (order.company_id = company.company_id)
WHERE company.company_id IN (split_str_to_ints($1))
GROUP BY order.id, order.company_id
ORDER BY order_count DESC;
```

```
EXECUTE get_orders('1,2,3,4')
```

But when I want to define the function I get an error saying that array of integers is not a supported plpythonu UDF return type.

Is there any way other way to pass list of integers (or chars) to a prepared statement on Redshift?

Comment: I doubt you can do that. The `IN` statement is expected to return 1 or more rows. A list is unlikely to fulfil those requirements.