# AWS Amazon Redshift driver bug with lists in clause IN

Tags: java, spring, amazon-redshift, driver

I'm using spring NamedParameterJdbcDaoSupport class with Redshift and I have a bug/crash when parameters are of type List/Set and have no element or have a single element (The weir case!).

_This is my artifact

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazon.redshift</groupId>
    <artifactId>redshift-jdbc42</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.41.1065</version>
</dependency>
```

*This is my table script*

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_table (
  id BIGINT NOT NULL,
  last_contact timestamp DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

*This is my dao code*

```
public class TestDao extends NamedParameterJdbcDaoSupport {
private static final String QUERY_INTEGER_ID = "SELECT id FROM test_table WHERE id IN (:ids) GROUP BY id";

    public TestDao(DataSource dataSource) {
        setDataSource(dataSource);
    }

    public List<Map<String, Object>> queryId(List<Integer> list) {
        MapSqlParameterSource params = new MapSqlParameterSource();
        params.addValue("ids", list);
        return getNamedParameterJdbcTemplate().queryForList(QUERY_INTEGER_ID, params);
    }

}
```

*This is my test class*

```
public class TheTestClass {

    // REDSHIFT > FAIL WITH ERROR "java.sql.SQLException: [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: syntax error at or near ')'"
   // H2 Memory database > Pass OK
    @Test
    public void testQueryId_WithEmptyList() {
        List<Map<String, Object>> result = dao.queryId(Collections.emptyList());
        Assertions.assertNotNull(result);
    }

    // REDSHIFT > FAIL WITH ERROR "SQL state [XX000]; error code [500310]; [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: Assert ... Query with multi-segment stream cannot be selective dispatched"
   // H2 Memory database > Pass OK
    @Test
    public void testQueryId_WithSingleElementList_Redshift() {
        List<Map<String, Object>> result = dao.queryId(Collections.singletonList(100));
        Assertions.assertNotNull(result);
    }

   // Redshift > Pass OK
   // H2 Memory database > Pass OK
    @Test
    public void testQueryId_WithMultipleElementsList_Redshift() {
        List<Map<String, Object>> result = dao.queryId(List.of(10,  20));
        Assertions.assertNotNull(result);
    }
}
```

**The most weird error is invoking dao method with a single element, this is part of the stack trace:**

```
org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [SELECT id FROM test_table WHERE id IN (?) GROUP BY id]; SQL state [XX000]; error code [500310]; [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: Assert
Details: 
 -----------------------------------------------
  error:  Assert
  code:      1000
  context:   IsSDDisabled(m_dispatch_level) || num_compute_segments == 1 - Query with multi-segment stream cannot be selective dispatched
  query:     7712953
  location:  query.cpp:1724
  process:   padbmaster [pid=28592]
  -----------------------------------------------;; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: Assert
Details: 
 -----------------------------------------------
  error:  Assert
  code:      1000
  context:   IsSDDisabled(m_dispatch_level) || num_compute_segments == 1 - Query with multi-segment stream cannot be selective dispatched
  query:     7712953
  location:  query.cpp:1724
  process:   padbmaster [pid=28592]
  -----------------------------------------------;
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:89)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.translateException(JdbcTemplate.java:1443)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:633)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:669)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:694)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:748)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:216)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForList(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:296)
    ...
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:675)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: Assert
Details: 
 -----------------------------------------------
  error:  Assert
  code:      1000
  context:   IsSDDisabled(m_dispatch_level) || num_compute_segments == 1 - Query with multi-segment stream cannot be selective dispatched
  query:     7712953
  location:  query.cpp:1724
  process:   padbmaster [pid=28592]
  -----------------------------------------------;
    at com.amazon.redshift.client.messages.inbound.ErrorResponse.toErrorException(Unknown Source)
    at com.amazon.redshift.client.PGMessagingContext.handleErrorResponse(Unknown Source)
    at com.amazon.redshift.client.PGMessagingContext.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
    at com.amazon.jdbc.communications.InboundMessagesPipeline.getNextMessageOfClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.amazon.redshift.client.PGMessagingContext.doMoveToNextClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.amazon.redshift.client.PGMessagingContext.getErrorResponse(Unknown Source)
    at com.amazon.redshift.client.PGClient.handleErrorsScenario2ForPrepareExecution(Unknown Source)
    at com.amazon.redshift.client.PGClient.handleErrorsPrepareExecute(Unknown Source)
    at com.amazon.redshift.dataengine.CallablePreparedOrAtomicExecuteTask.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.amazon.redshift.dataengine.CallablePreparedOrAtomicExecuteTask.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
Caused by: com.amazon.support.exceptions.ErrorException: [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: Assert
Details: 
 -----------------------------------------------
  error:  Assert
  code:      1000
  context:   IsSDDisabled(m_dispatch_level) || num_compute_segments == 1 - Query with multi-segment stream cannot be selective dispatched
  query:     7712953
  location:  query.cpp:1724
  process:   padbmaster [pid=28592]
  -----------------------------------------------;
    ... 13 more
```

I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: It would really improve the readability of the error log if you post it as a code block instead of a quote block.

Comment: Thank you! I edited as you suggested

Comment: You could examine the contents of the [STL_QUERYTEXT](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_STL_QUERYTEXT.html) table to see the actual SQL command that was sent to Redshift. You could then try running the command yourself directly in Redshift. This should give you a hint whether it is sending invalid SQL, or if Redshift is incorrectly processing the command. Let us know what you find!

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid in Redshift you just cannot pass lists or array to `IN` operator in prepared statement. I've tried as well and it didn't work. I found no evidence of this in the docs, only [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55091519/750510#comment96928282_55091519) on StackOverflow.